# Triangle Vector Geometry Proof

Tags: geometry, vectors

Take a triangle $\triangle PQR$ in the plane. Let $\overrightarrow A$ be the vector with the same length as $\overrightarrow {PQ}$, but perpendicular to it, and pointing outside of the triangle. Using similar vectors $\overrightarrow B$ and $\overrightarrow C$, prove that ${\overrightarrow A + \overrightarrow B + \overrightarrow C = 0}$ without computation.

My attempt below:

I know that $\overrightarrow {PQ},$ $\overrightarrow {QR}$ and $\overrightarrow {RP}$ sum to $0$ but I don't know how to proceed with my question. What I did was I drew a triangle on graph paper, took their perpendiculars and rearranged said perpendiculars and indeed I got 0. I can also do something similar by taking 3 random plane vectors that form a triangle, rotating them by 90° and indeed they would sum to zero. But the question required that I answer this question using a sentence and not a computation.

Comment: You state that A, B, C are in the plane or not?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, kindly show us what you tried to get the answer . Simply posing the question is not how it works

Comment: The question did not state whether or not A, B and C are in the same plane. I'm guessing they are.

Answer (score 2):

Just rotate the whole triangle by $90^o$. By rotating the triangle by ninety degrees, $\vec{PQ}$ becomes $\vec{A}$, $\vec{QR}$ becomes $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{RP}$ becomes $\vec{C}$

Thus ABC forms a triangle.

$\implies\vec{A}+\vec{B}+\vec{C}=0 $

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$\vec{PQ}+\vec{QR}+\vec{RP}=\vec{0}$
$\vec{A}.\vec{PQ}=\vec{0}$
$\vec{B}.\vec{QR}=\vec{0}$
$\vec{C}.\vec{RS}=\vec{0}$

If these A.B,C lie in the same plane of original $\Delta PQR$. You can easily form them into a new triangle and use the property of the triangle that the cyclic vector sum is $\vec{0}$.

Comment: Thanks! I will keep in mind to post my own attempt next time.